# Page expired just when hosting my laravel app

Tags: hosting, laravel-9, inertiajs, laravel-breeze, expired-sessions

My laravel app is working fine at localhost, but when I deploy it in server, after login I have a `419 error page expired`, I don't know what is the error !! I mention the csrf token in `app.blade.php` but nothing was solved.

I use Laravel 9, laravel breeze for authentication, Inertia for routing, vueJs 3 and vite js.

All my routes are in `web.php`

My app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
        <title inertia>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
        <!-- Scripts -->
        @routes
        @vite('resources/js/app.js')
        @inertiaHead
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        @inertia
    </body>
</html>
```

my session.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | While using one of the framework's cache driven session backends you may
    | list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
    | must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
    |
    | Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
    |
    */

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you when it can't be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | will set this value to "lax" since this is a secure default value.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
    |
    */

    'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

and .end :

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=support.demkit.fr
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
```

Any suggestions to resolve this issue !! the problem is at localhost everything works fine ...

Comment: If you are trying to submit a form, remember to add the `@csrf` blade directive within your `<form></form>`

Comment: Inertia automatically adds the CSFR token in every POST request. With Laravel it's done underneath by Axios., not sure what is happening though.